# Bootstrap 4 - Fix Column Widths with input/select menu

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a simple table with 9 columns - I'm using the last row to allow the user to add data to the table and I'm using a select menu on one of the inputs to let users choose from a list.

It appears that adding this last row/select menu causes the column to increase in width to accommodate the largest option in the select menu overriding the column widths I've set in the table header rows.

Here's the table without the last input/row:

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th width=15%>Product No</th>
    <th width=25%>Product Name</th>
    <th width=5%>Stage</th>
    <th width=15%>Stage Name</th>
    <th width=5%>Day</th>
    <th width=5%>Time</th>
    <th width=5%>Total</th>
    <th width=20%>Memo</th>
    <th width=5%>Activity</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="1686178">
      <td>34521</td>
      <td>Block A</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Start</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="1686179">
      <td>63212</td>
      <td>Sports Field</td>
      <td>05</td>
      <td>Middle</td>
      <td>Fri</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

and here's how it looks with the input row added:

```html
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th width=15%>Product No</th>
    <th width=25%>Product Name</th>
    <th width=5%>Stage</th>
    <th width=15%>Stage Name</th>
    <th width=5%>Day</th>
    <th width=5%>Time</th>
    <th width=5%>Total</th>
    <th width=20%>Memo</th>
    <th width=5%>Activity</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="1686178">
      <td>34521</td>
      <td>Block A</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Start</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="1686179">
      <td>63212</td>
      <td>Sports Field</td>
      <td>05</td>
      <td>Middle</td>
      <td>Fri</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td><select name="ProjectNumber">
   <option value=""></option> 
   <option value="34521">Block A</option><option value="63212">Sports Field</option><option value="985214">Underground Car Park</option><option value="521478">Main Campus Library</option>    
          </select></td>
      <td id="ProjectName"></td>
      <td id="ProjectPhases"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><select name="Date">
         <option value=""></option>            
            <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
               <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
               <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
               <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
               <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
               <option value="Sat">Sat</option>
               <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
             </select></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Time"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Notes"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="9">
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a way to keep the width of the columns the same so they don't resize and grow wider as that makes the table expand in size when I would like it to remain the size same as it does when there is no input row at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specify `Width:100%;` for `select`

```css
select{
width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <th width=15%>Product No</th>
    <th width=25%>Product Name</th>
    <th width=5%>Stage</th>
    <th width=15%>Stage Name</th>
    <th width=5%>Day</th>
    <th width=5%>Time</th>
    <th width=5%>Total</th>
    <th width=20%>Memo</th>
    <th width=5%>Activity</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr id="1686178">
      <td>34521</td>
      <td>Block A</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>Start</td>
      <td>Mon</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr id="1686179">
      <td>63212</td>
      <td>Sports Field</td>
      <td>05</td>
      <td>Middle</td>
      <td>Fri</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
      <td><select name="ProjectNumber">
   <option value=""></option> 
   <option value="34521">Block A</option><option value="63212">Sports Field</option><option value="985214">Underground Car Park</option><option value="521478">Main Campus Library</option>    
          </select></td>
      <td id="ProjectName"></td>
      <td id="ProjectPhases"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><select name="Date">
         <option value=""></option>            
            <option value="Mon">Mon</option>
               <option value="Tue">Tue</option>
               <option value="Wed">Wed</option>
               <option value="Thu">Thu</option>
               <option value="Fri">Fri</option>
               <option value="Sat">Sat</option>
               <option value="Sun">Sun</option>
             </select></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Time"></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Notes"></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td colspan="9">
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: There's also an `w-100` class available.